# Error while generating a file: Invalid argument: value in Settings.settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

The compiler tells me:

```
 Error while generating a file: Invalid argument: value in Settings.settings
```

And when I click this error, it opens up the Settings.settings file.

Does anybody see anything wrong in here?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<SettingsFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/01/settings" CurrentProfile="(Default)">
  <Profiles>
    <Profile Name="(Default)" />
  </Profiles>
</SettingsFile>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this by adding a Custom Tool Namespace.